# My mxd is a word file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, windows-10

I just installed Windows 10, and I have ArcGIS 10.3. Now, when I use any script to create a new .mxd map document (and occasionally if I download an .mxd made on another computer), it shows up as a Microsoft word file, i.e. MAP.mxd.doc. I can't open it with ArcMap (even by searching for another program to use it, and selecting ArcMap as the program).

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: ESRI doesn't support windows 10 yet and I've seen some weird ArcGIS behavior when I've upgraded machines to 10. What is the exact error you are getting? What do you mean by using a script to create a new arcmap? Have you tried renaiming the .mxd file to remove the .doc part of the file name?

Comment: According to [this article](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/45362), ArcGIS 10.3.1 supports Windows 10. Can you install 10.3.1?

Comment: I'm assuming that this did/would go away by upgrading to 10.3.1, and so will close the question as non-reproducible.  If it persists at that version then just [edit] your question to update it with that information which should trigger its re-opening, if not you can flag us to request re-opening.

Comment: Reproduced here -- someone just sent me a .mxd.doc, and it was good to find this post.