# .MXD file shows as *.DOC file after upgrading machine with ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop to Windows 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, mxd, file-formats, windows-10

I created an .mxd file on a computer with an earlier version of Windows (I was at a college campus; not sure what version). Now, on a computer with Windows 10, the file appears as a Word .DOC and ArcMap cannot open it.  My only idea was to reassign the default software type that opens the file, but that did not work.

[My mxd is a word file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165213/my-mxd-is-a-word-file) cites a similar problem and says installing ArcGIS 10.3.1 on the Windows 10 machine will fix it, but I already have ArcGIS 10.3.1 installed. Also I don't think that would be the problem, because I can open other .mxd files, and Windows Explorer is interpreting the file as .DOC regardless of ArcGIS being installed or not.

Any tips for converting this back to an .mxd I can open on a Windows 10 machine using ArcGIS 10.3.1?

Comment: Uninstalling and Reinstalling ArcGIS 10.3.1 would re-establish the file association if it has been broken, which is possibly why it is the suggested fix.

Comment: The file association has not been broken; I can open .mxd files created on this Windows 10 machine using this same install of ArcGIS 10.3.1.  The problem is only with the .mxd file I have transferred from the other computer.

Comment: Is the extension for this file still `.mxd`?  If not, have you changed the extension to correct it?

Comment: Thank you! I just made file extensions visible via File Explorer Options and changed the extension to .MXD and it worked. The file had ".mxd" in the title so I didn't realize that wasn't the actual file extension. Had to google that... I'm a total novice at anything past Windows XP!

Comment: One of the most serious security vulnerabilities of Windows is Microsoft's refusal to disable "hide known extensions". Failure to immediately disable this known weakness is a major mistake, no matter what version of Windows is in use.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Steph in a comment:

> I just made file extensions visible via File Explorer Options and
>   changed the extension to .MXD and it worked. The file had ".mxd" in
>   the title so I didn't realize that wasn't the actual file extension.